# One set of dynamically generated controls for two sliding lists (jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the Easy Slider plugin ([http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding)](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding%29) to scroll several lists. The plugin dynamically generates the controls for the lists. So there are two sets of controls showing up. I was wondering if I could bind the controls into a single set. I would like the single controls to slide/scroll both lists at the same time. The reason I am doing this I have 100% width background that I want to scroll the same time as a "feature" div inside my wrapper. The layout/css is working great - just need a hand with the js.

FUNCTION

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slides, #slideTop").easySlider({
                auto: true,
                continuous: true,
                numeric: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="slides">
<ul>
<li class="slideOne"></li>
<li class="slideTwo"></li>
<li class="slideThree"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container_16">
<div class="grid_16">
<div id="slideTop">
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideTop{
    width:940px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slides{
    width:100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:144px;
    z-index: -9999;
    overflow: hidden;

}


#slideTop ul {
    padding:0;
    width: 940px;
    height: 350px;
}

#slideTop ul li {
    height:350px;
    list-style:none;
    width: 940px;
}

#slides ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

#slides ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:350px;
    list-style:none;
    width:4000px;
    float: left;
}

.slideOne {
    background: url(images/one.gif) repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

.slideTwo {
    background: url(images/two.gif) repeat-x;
        width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

.slideThree {
    background: url(images/three.gif) repeat-x;
        width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

ul#controls {
    height:21px;
    padding:0;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
    top:620px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:430px
}

ul#controls li {
    float:left;
    height:21px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 3px;
    width:21px
}

ul#controls li a {
    background:url(images/ss.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:21px;
    width:21px;
    border:none
}
```

Comment: text says `cycle` plugin, code shows `easyslider`plugin

Comment: Rats! Good catch @charlietfl. I am using the Easy Slider. I have updated the information/code.